# How to hide a grid tile in a grid list in angular material design?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I am new to material design. I was implementing a grid list using angular material design. But suddenly I needed to hide one tile.

Can anyone tell that how to hide a tile in grid list. If I explicitly set "display" property to none then the space remains blank but not occupied by other tiles.

Here is my Grid list

```
<md-grid-list
        md-cols-sm="1" md-cols-md="1" md-cols-gt-md="3"
        md-row-height-sm="2:1" md-row-height-md="2:1" md-row-height-gt-md="1:1"
        md-gutter="12px" md-gutter-gt-sm="8px" >
    <md-grid-tile md-colspan-gt-md="2">
        <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z2 slider" layout layout-align="center center">
            <ul rn-carousel class="image" rn-carousel-auto-slide>
                <li><img src="images/american-cuisine.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"/></li>
                <li><img src="images/indian-cuisine.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"/></li>
                <li><img src="images/italian-cuisine.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"/></li>
                <li><img src="images/japanese-cuisine.jpg" alt="" width="100%" height="100%"/></li>
            </ul>
        </md-whiteframe>
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile>
        <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z2 login" layout layout-align="center center">
            <span>.md-whiteframe-z1</span>
        </md-whiteframe>
    </md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hide the tile without leaving a blank space. This is because the tile's location is determined when the grid is loaded. The right way to do it is to remove the tile and re-render the grid.

Comment: I think you were trying to mean tile.

Comment: That sounds good, but how can I re-render the grid? (I am new to Angular Material and AngularJS as well).

Comment: @MichalMoravcik You should start a new question because this is going to take a lot of time to break it down.

Comment: @MichalMoravcik, did you find the answer to how to re-render the tile?

Comment: @SajibAcharya, no I haven't. I am using UI Bootstrap together with customized Bootswatch Paper theme instead of Angular Material. Maybe I will come to this again later.

Comment: we can hide by passing rowHeigth based on condition something like
 -----------------> rowHeight="{{rowHeight}}px"
0 if u want to hide else some value to show :)